# windows control button bug

Tags: gnome, configuration, 18.04, window-buttons

i am facing an error in the windows control button, please see below screenshots, i have changed to other themes but did not work, this is only happening in the terminal, at other places but I have not yet found.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know the answer but how about using Terminator instead, I like it better than the default terminal app anyway. sudo apt install terminator

Answer (score 2):

Please read this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes/+bug/1718238) carefully to confirm you are having the same problem.

If so review all the comments. Of particular interest is comment #8:

```
sudo apt install gnome-icon-theme # fixes
sudo apt purge gnome-icon-theme # breaks
```

I don't have this problem using **Unity** on 18.04 LTS so I hope this helps you.